# Root able to login but non root users are denied - PAM

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, troubleshooting

One of our servers is not letting non-root users login, but root can login without any issues.
The following are the messages from `/var/log/secure`:

```
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: debug1: attempt 2 failures 2
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: debug1: keyboard-interactive devs
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: debug1: auth2_challenge: user=user.name ting=
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices 'pam'
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: debug1: auth2_challenge_start: trying authentication method 'pam'
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for user.name from 10.10.10.10 port 57775 ssh2
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: Received disconnect from 10.10.10.10: 13: Unable to authenticate
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14470]: debug1: do_cleanup
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14466]: debug1: do_cleanup
Jun 24 18:08:43 jonnserver sshd[14466]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Jun 24 18:09:01 jonnserver crond[14482]: pam_limits(crond:session): invalid line 'hard core 0' - skipped
Jun 24 18:09:01 jonnserver crond[14483]: pam_limits(crond:session): invalid line 'hard core 0' - skipped
```

Comment: Your log is missing a lot of information. It doesn't show *why* the authentication failed which is the critical bit. Please include from the `Connection from` line until what you've currently provided.

Comment: Try running `ssh -vvv <username>@<host>`.  You should get loads of debugging info which may explain why it's failing.

Comment: Is any file system full or near full?  root can use the last n% of disk space when regular users cannot.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.  We found out that it was due to one of the software we use for the authentication.  The restart of that software did the work for us.